# Replicating gradient boosting model using scikit-learn's classifier in xgboost and LightGBM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, lightgbm

I have a small dataset (28 entries) in which I have been doing a churn analysis using a gradient-boosting model with Python's Scikit-Learn with great results apparently: I have 100% accuracy in the test data.

However, as you know, `Scikit-Learn`'s classifier is very computationally intensive and slow, so I would like to replicate this model using more computationally efficient modules, such as `xgboost` and `LightGBM`, but I haven't been successful in this goal.

Here is the predictor matrix I called `X2`

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.071429 | 0.071429 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.071429 |
| 0.043478 | 0.043478 | 0.130435 | 0.043478 | 0.043478 | 0.043478 | 0.130435 | 0.043478 |
| 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.043478 | 0.130435 | 0.000000 | 0.130435 | 0.043478 | 0.086957 |
| 0.043478 | 0.000000 | 0.043478 | 0.086957 | 0.000000 | 0.173913 | 0.043478 | 0.130435 |
| 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.055556 | 0.000000 |
| 0.086957 | 0.173913 | 0.086957 | 0.000000 | 0.260870 | 0.000000 | 0.043478 | 0.043478 |
| 0.086957 | 0.086957 | 0.086957 | 0.043478 | 0.043478 | 0.043478 | 0.000000 | 0.130435 |
| 0.043478 | 0.043478 | 0.000000 | 0.086957 | 0.043478 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.043478 |
| 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.071429 | 0.000000 | 0.071429 | 0.142857 | 0.071429 |
| 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.142857 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.142857 |
| 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.043478 | 0.043478 |
| 0.043478 | 0.000000 | 0.043478 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.086957 | 0.000000 | 0.086957 |
| 0.000000 | 0.043478 | 0.000000 | 0.086957 | 0.173913 | 0.086957 | 0.043478 | 0.043478 |
| 0.000000 | 0.086957 | 0.000000 | 0.043478 | 0.260870 | 0.043478 | 0.130435 | 0.000000 |
| 0.043478 | 0.043478 | 0.000000 | 0.043478 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.043478 | 0.000000 |
| 0.086957 | 0.086957 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.217391 | 0.043478 | 0.043478 | 0.043478 |
| 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.318182 | 0.136364 | 0.000000 | 0.045455 | 0.000000 |
| 0.043478 | 0.000000 | 0.086957 | 0.086957 | 0.260870 | 0.217391 | 0.130435 | 0.043478 |
| 0.043478 | 0.000000 | 0.130435 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.125000 | 0.125000 | 0.125000 |
| 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.043478 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 0.086957 | 0.043478 | 0.130435 | 0.217391 | 0.043478 | 0.173913 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.043478 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 |
| 0.260870 | 0.086957 | 0.000000 | 0.043478 | 0.086957 | 0.043478 | 0.086957 | 0.000000 |

and my response variable `y`

```
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
```

These are the parameters I have used in the `Scikit-Learn` classifier and on which I have performed a grid search using `Scikit-Learn`'s `GridSearchCV`:

```
gboost_parameters = {'loss': ['log_loss','exponential'],'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.05, 0.1],
                     'n_estimators': [20, 50, 100], 'criterion': ['friedman_mse', 'squared_error'],'min_samples_split': [5, 6, 7],
                     'min_samples_leaf': [3, 4, 5], 'max_depth': [1, 2, 3],
                     'min_impurity_decrease': [0.05, 0.1, 0.2], 'max_features': ['sqrt', 'log2']}
```

I have split the data into training and test sets and fitted the model with a 4-fold cross-validation

```
X2_train, X2_test, y2_train, y2_test = train_test_split(X2, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=32)

gbm2_cv = GridSearchCV(
    GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=32,loss='log-loss',min_samples_split=5,min_samples_leaf=3,validation_fraction=0.2),
    gboost_parameters, cv=4)
gbm2_cv.fit(X2_train,y2_train)
```

Then I obtained the following output

```
print("Tuned hyperparameters :",gbm2_cv.best_params_)
print("Accuracy in the training set :",gbm2_cv.best_score_)
print("Gradient boosting model accuracy: ", gbm2_cv.score(X2_test,y2_test))

Tuned hyperparameters : {'criterion': 'friedman_mse', 'learning_rate': 0.05, 'loss': 'log_loss', 'max_depth': 1, 'max_features': 'sqrt', 'min_impurity_decrease': 0.05, 'min_samples_leaf': 3, 'min_samples_split': 5, 'n_estimators': 50}
Accuracy in the training set: 0.9
Gradient boosting model accuracy:  1.0
```

Now how do I replicate this model in the other packages?
I tried to use the equivalent parameters but to no avail.

Here is my attempt using `xgboost`:

```
xgboost_parameters = {
    'objective': ['binary:logistic','binary:logitraw'],
    'alpha': [0, 0.1, 0.2],
    'lambda':[0, 0.1, 0.2],
    'learning_rate': [0.05],
    'n_estimators': [20, 50, 100],
    'max_depth': [1, 2],
    'min_child_weight': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'gamma': [0.05],
    'colsample_bytree': [0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
}

xgb2_cv = GridSearchCV(xgb.XGBClassifier(random_state=32, eval_metric='logloss'), xgboost_parameters, cv=4)
xgb2_cv.fit(X2_train, y2_train)
```

which has resulted in an underfit

```
print("Tuned hyperparameters :",xgb2_cv.best_params_)
print("Accuracy on training data:",xgb2_cv.best_score_)
print("Accuracy on test data:",xgb2_cv.score(X2_test,y2_test))

Tuned hyperparameters : {'alpha': 0, 'colsample_bytree': 0.3, 'gamma': 0.05, 'lambda': 0, 'learning_rate': 0.05, 'max_depth': 1, 'min_child_weight': 3, 'n_estimators': 20, 'objective': 'binary:logitraw'}
Accuracy on training data: 0.475
Accuracy on test data: 0.2222222222222222
```

Here is my attempt using `LightGBM`:

```
lgbm_parameters = {'objective': ['binary'],
                  'boosting_type': ['gbdt'],
                  'num_iterations': [20, 50, 100],
                  'learning_rate': [0.01, 0.05, 0.1],
                  'deterministic': [False],
                  'force_col_wise': [True],
                  'max_depth': [1, 2],
                  'colsample_bytree': [0.3, 1/3, 0.4],
                  'min_split_gain': [0],
                  'min_child_samples': [3, 4, 5],
                   'min_data_in_bin': [5, 6, 7]
                  }

lgb_cv = GridSearchCV(lgb.LGBMClassifier(random_state=32), lgbm_parameters, cv=4)
lgb_cv.fit(X2_train, y2_train)
```

and this was the best I got

```
print("Tuned hyperparameters :",lgb_cv.best_params_)
print("Accuracy on training data:",lgb_cv.best_score_)
print("Accuracy on test data:",lgb_cv.score(X2_test,y2_test))

Tuned hyperparameters : {'boosting_type': 'gbdt', 'colsample_bytree': 0.3, 'deterministic': False, 'force_col_wise': True, 'learning_rate': 0.05, 'max_depth': 1, 'min_child_samples': 3, 'min_data_in_bin': 5, 'min_split_gain': 0, 'n_iter': 20, 'objective': 'binary'}
Accuracy on training data: 0.8500000000000001
Accuracy on test data: 0.7777777777777778
```

From what I can see, most of the equivalent parameters had the same values, with few exceptions. In the `LightGBM` classifier model, the number of estimators was only 20, but raising this number to 50 does not change these results. The only other difference I found was that in the `Scikit-Learn` classifier we can use the Friedman mean squared error to evaluate the quality of the splits, which is probably what I cannot replicate in other models... can I?
I don't know what other differences there are here, but as you can see I cannot replicate what I obtained from the `Scikit-Learn` classifier in the `xgboost` and `LightGBM` classifiers.